# Making a flat base for model

Tags: modeling

**Hi**
I have a question: is there any easy way to extend only the bottom edges of an irregular model (such as in the screenshot) and create a flat base of the model to get the effect shown in the attached drawing?

Thanks in advance for the advice!

[image: My model]

[image: What I want to do with the model]

Comment: Hi! Welcome. A search on 'Flat Base' returns quite a few previous answers, on this site. Please check those out first, SE sites try to avoid duplicated answers.

Comment: Thanks, that would be exactly what I need, but how to make base for irregular shapes?

Comment: Hello, it looks like your mesh requires at least a bit of retopology, the holes won't bode well with the linked technique